# Re-adding disk to md raid fails

Tags: linux, debian, raid, software-raid

I have a problem with a Linux software raid and don't know what are the next steps to overcome this.
It's a Raid 1 of several partitions. After an unclean shutdown the raid started unclean degraded with the partition removes. I cannot re-add it manually.

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
          Version : 1.2
    Creation Time : Sat Jul 30 18:32:37 2022
       Raid Level : raid1
       Array Size : 100596736 (95.94 GiB 103.01 GB)
    Used Dev Size : 100596736 (95.94 GiB 103.01 GB)
     Raid Devices : 4
    Total Devices : 3
      Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      Update Time : Fri Feb  3 18:19:37 2023
            State : clean, degraded
   Active Devices : 3
  Working Devices : 3
   Failed Devices : 0
    Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

             Name : rescue:2
             UUID : 0aa4403a:125a1f94:d325179e:1c5ea540
           Events : 962235

   Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
      0       8       51        0      active sync   /dev/sdd3
      2       8        3        1      active sync   /dev/sda3
      3       8       35        2      active sync   /dev/sdc3
      -       0        0        3      removed
```

I try `mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdb3` but then I get `mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sdb3 as 4: Invalid argument` and dmesg shows

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 35655689
ata3: EH complete
md: disabled device sdb3, could not read superblock.
md: sdb3 does not have a valid v1.2 superblock, not importing!
md: md_import_device returned -22
```

Examine confirms there is no superblock:

```
mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdb3
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb3.
```

Due to the read error I have ran badblocks but after that the error is still there.
So my question is, if there is a way to re-add the partition to the raid array and how.

Smart shows test result as passed:

```
smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-4.19.0-21-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Now I am really wondering if change of drive is required or if there is a way to get around the I/O error that seems to prevent the drive being re-added to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sdb` had failed:

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 35655689
```

Badblocks will not help here; it *can* help for filesystems, while MD RAID on-disk structure is not a filesystem. And a bad block happened exactly where MD expects to have a superblock; it doesn't have a backup superblock or a facility to relocate it, so if this particular space is broken the device is absolutely unusable for MD RAID. (There are four superblock version formats, which place it in different areas of the disk, but you have already built your array and you can't change the version on the fly.)

Replace the physical drive. It is dangerous to use.

I also suggest you to read its SMART data, to see this better. But the error message speaks for itself, it is enough to say the drive is failing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I understand correctly that the broken sector is the sector for the superblock and thats why the partition cant be re-added to the array? And it cannot be remapped or something?
When I put a new disk instead, what is the correct way to add it to the array? Would the ```mdadm --add``` command be sufficient?

Comment: Added smart test result in original post.

Comment: No, that's not a "smart rest result". Please, do `smartctl --all /dev/sdb`; we want to see properties attributes, error log, instead of its own verdict, which is almost always overly optimistic. // You'll need to partition it in compartible way (read "the same way") and then add into the array with mdadm --add. And, if this drive was expected to be bootable, you'll need to install a boot loader on it (with MD RAID you always make several drives bootable).